# Descend from vs be descended from

Tags: phrase-meaning

What's the difference between them?

I don't quite understand as they have quite similar meaning according to what I managed to understand from Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: Did you get confused in a particular sentence? Can you please provide it? Or is it general?

Comment: I believe there is not much of a difference. You can find this in the [second entry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/descend-from-someone-something) from Cambridge Dictionary itself.

Comment: No particular sentence, it's general.